# What do the numbers after command and system call names mean in *nix?

Tags: linux, posix, system-calls, freebsd, manpage

I often see number-suffixed command or system call names in man pages or other documentation, for example, [`splice(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/splice.2.html).
Although, some publications don't include the numbers, for example, [Splice on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_(system_call)).

I never found an explanation of what the numbers stand for and don't even know where/how to begin a search.

1. What do these numbers mean?
2. What is the range for these numbers?
3. Why are they suffixed to function and command names?
4. Which communities use those numbers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Unix & Linux site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the number in parentheses shown after Unix command names in manpages mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-parentheses-shown-after-unix-command-names-in-manpages-m)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These numbers refer to Unix man sections.

```
1   Commands available to users
2   Unix and C system calls
3   C library routines for C programs
4   Special file names
5   File formats and conventions for files used by Unix
6   Games
7   Word processing packages
8   System administration commands and procedures
```

You can specify a section number with the `man` command by just listing the section number:

```
man 1 somecommand
```

would  look for `somecommand` in section 1 of the man pages.

Wikipedia has some [additional information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) on this as does this page on [how to use man pages](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-linux-unix-man-pages/).

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. Now I will no longer feel discriminated against by man page writers :)