# Decoding a man page

Tags: unix, manpage

I'm taking the `git` man page as an example, but I have seen the example I am about to use many places throughout UNIX/Linux.

Under the `git` man page, it has the following header:

```
Main Porcelain Commands
```

Underneath this header, there are a lot of commands with dashes between such as:

```
git-clone
```

Since that is headed under `Commands` you would assume that it means `git-clone` is a command (I very well know `git clone [directory]` is a valid.

But it appears that it isn't - so why does the man page list `git-clone` as being a command? The man pages *are* good, if you can decode them right.

Comment: You can call `man git-clone` and get a man page specific for git clone. Not sure if that's the reasoning for that notation in the `man git` page but *shrug*.

Comment: Thanks - so to follow up with your comment, where does it say it's a man page (or am I missing something)?

Comment: Note that originally there was no `git` executable; you actually ran a binary called `git-clone`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

On my system it says `git-clone(1)`. It is the name of a `man` page about a command not a command itself.

`man git-clone` gives:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>       git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
> ```

… showing it with the space instead of the dash.

Comment: Thanks! Where on the man page does it say that `git-clone` is another man page?

Comment: *Pages are traditionally referred to using the notation "name(section)": for example, ftp(1)* — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-parentheses-shown-after-unix-command-names-mean

Answer (score 0):

> HIGH-LEVEL COMMANDS (PORCELAIN)
> We separate the porcelain commands into the main commands and some
> ancillary user utilities.
> Main porcelain commands
> git-add(1) Add file content

The above text has been taken from `man git`.
Now whenever you see any text with `(x)` appended to it it means that there is a separate man page for that..
So here, in your case you do not have to use the command `git-clone` but do a `man git-clone` to get the man page for `git clone` command.