# Numerical suffix after entry name in Git's docs

Tags: git

In Git docs you can see a numerical suffix after entry name, for example:

- [git(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)
- [git-clone(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html)
- [gitrepository-layout(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html)
- [gitworkflows(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html)
- [gittutorial(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html)

What do those suffix mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This number suffix is the manual section. Notice `Introduction to Volume 1` in http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/v7vol1.pdf.  There are different sections of which:

- 1 is commands
- 5 is file format and convention and
- 7 is macro packages and language conventions

git(1) indicates that git manual/doc relates to section 1. gitrepository-layout(5) indicates that gitrepository-layout manual/doc relates to section 5.

On GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) when I do `man git`, Git Manual shows GIT(1). I could also write `man 1 git` to get to the same page.

There are some commands such as `info` that may appear in multiple sections such as section 1 and section 5. In such cases info(1) and info(5) can be used for clarification and based on that one could find information about info using `man 1 info` and `man 5 info`. I don't know if any git commands fall in multiple section but the convention is still followed.

Also see this answer: [What does the number in parentheses shown after Unix command names mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-parentheses-shown-after-unix-command-names-mean)