# What does the (2) after Unix system calls names mean?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I was looking through some documentations for my university task and noticed that all of the syscalls there are followed by (2), like execv(2), fork(2) or fcntl(2). What do they represent?

Comment: Try `man man` :)

Comment: This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the number in parentheses shown after Unix command names in manpages mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-parentheses-shown-after-unix-command-names-in-manpages-m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Linux man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/) are grouped in sections. Section 2 is "System calls (functions provided by the kernel".

> 1. Executable programs or shell commands
> 2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
> 3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)
> 4. Special files (usually found in /dev)
> 5. File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
> 6. Games
> 7. Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
> 8. System administration commands (usually only for root)
> 9. Kernel routines [Non standard]

Some man pages, such as `unlink` exist in several categories (e.g. 1 and 2), so to browse the page of a specific category, run `man section page` (e.g. `man 2 unlink` to browse the syscall manual) or `man page.section` (e.g. `man unlink.2`).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same approved answer in this post:

[What does the number in parentheses shown after Unix command names in manpages mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-parentheses-shown-after-unix-command-names-in-manpages-m)

"It's the section that the man page for the command is assigned to.

These are split as

General commands
System calls
C library functions
Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
File formats and conventions
Games and screensavers
Miscellanea
System administration commands and daemons
Original descriptions of each section can be seen in the Unix Programmer's Manual (page ii)."